# How can I import 2 different timezones to check if it is Monday in both?

Tags: c++

Hopefully this makes sense, but I basically want the program to check if it is Monday in 2 different timezones. If it is, it should print something and if not print something else. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sometimething>
using namespace std;

int a = timezone A;
int b = timezone B;

int main() 
{
  if (a == mday() || b == mday())
  {
    cout << "Something1\n";
  } 
  else
  {
    cout << "Something2\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In which environment are you working?

Read [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) on local time function.

They provide a great example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h> // defines putenv in POSIX

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << "UTC:       " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&t), "%c %Z") << '\n';
    std::cout << "local:     " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%c %Z") << '\n';
    // POSIX-specific:
    std::string tz = "TZ=Asia/Singapore";
    putenv(tz.data());
    std::cout << "Singapore: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%c %Z") << '\n';
}
```

Which outputs:

```
UTC:       Fri Sep 15 14:16:29 2017 GMT
local:     Fri Sep 15 14:16:29 2017 UTC
Singapore: Fri Sep 15 22:16:29 2017 SGT
```

You can define your own time zones to retrieve their local time.

Answer (score 0):

One could use [Howard Hinnant's preview of the C++20 chrono time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to do this.  The preview works with C++11 and later on Linux, Windows and macOS.  Though the example below takes advantage of C++17's CTAD feature (easy to work around in C++11/14).  [Some installation is required.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

bool
is_same_weekday(date::time_zone const* a,
                date::time_zone const* b, date::weekday wd)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    weekday wda{floor<days>(zoned_time{a, now}.get_local_time())};
    weekday wdb{floor<days>(zoned_time{b, now}.get_local_time())};
    return wd == wda && wd == wdb;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    if (is_same_weekday(locate_zone("America/New_York"),
                        locate_zone("Asia/Tokyo"), Monday))
        cout << "Something1\n";
    else
        cout << "Something2\n";
}
```

The function accepts two `time_zone const*`, and a `weekday`.  It first computes the current time (UTC, stored in `now`).  Then it creates a `zoned_time` for each `time_zone` with the current time.  By getting the local time out of each `zoned_time`, and truncating the local time to `days` precision, the local `weekday` can be extracted from each `zoned_time`.

This technique is thread safe in that one doesn't have to change the computer's local time zone to make this computation.

The client uses `locate_zone` to map `time_zone` names into `time_zone const*` to pass to `is_same_weekday`.  The client also passes in the `constexpr` `weekday` one wishes to compare against (`Monday` in this example).